# Packet's Padding Byte

Tags: c#, byte, padding

I am working on a small minecraft implementation project for my IT Coursework. I'm implementing the 'Classic Extension Protocol' which allows for more features e.t.c.

Mine isn't a problem, just a question, how would I go about checking a packet's padding byte? (It is required to determine whether a player is connecting from a standard client or an extension client). Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FemtoCraft](http://femto.fcraft.net/) source to understand, Here's an example of coding ExtAddPlayerName packet for sending to clients:

```
public static Packet ExtAddPlayerName(short nameid, string name, string ListName, string group, byte perm)
        {
            Packet packet = new Packet(OpCode.ExtAddPlayerName);
            ToNetOrder(nameid, packet.Bytes, 1);
            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name.PadRight(64), 0, 64, packet.Bytes, 3);
            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ListName.PadRight(64), 0, 64, packet.Bytes, 67);
            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(group.PadRight(64), 0, 64, packet.Bytes, 131);
            packet.Bytes[132] = perm;
            return packet;
        }

internal static void ToNetOrder( short number, byte[] arr, int offset ) {
            arr[offset] = (byte)( ( number & 0xff00 ) >> 8 );
            arr[offset + 1] = (byte)( number & 0x00ff );
        }
```

You set the exact location of bytes you're going to send, like a map.
As It's described on [this](http://wiki.vg/Classic_Protocol_Extension) page, It has the location of bytes, all you have to do is set them. you send byte[] to clients, byte[0] determines the Packet, by setting a new Packet yourpack = new Packet(PacketName) Your byte[0] automatically gets the packet name on fCraft / femtocraft.
About getting packets from clients, you can use OpCode variables:

```
OpCode opcode = reader.ReadOpCode();
                        switch( opcode ) {

                            case OpCode.Message:
                                if( !ProcessMessagePacket() ) return;
                                break;
```

Comment: Cheers mate, will have a look at it :)

Comment: This is helpful, but it's not quite what I was looking for, I was wondering, once you receive the Player Identification packet, how you then read the padding and check whether they're using the CPE?

Comment: This is the part I'm trying to do: "server must read the ClientIdentification packet and check its padding byte. If this byte is set to 0x42 (66 decimal), assume that the client supports CPE"

Comment: @SamSkipsFowler There's a packet that runs once player connects, You can see on [classic](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Classic_server_protocol) packets There's an unused packet, On FemtoCraft search 0x42 on whole solution and you'll find the place I'm talking about.